# Allow a way to hide the question list using the iPad app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, question-lists, ipad

In the iPad app, when viewing a question from the main list, it can get quite thin in portrait mode. Since that wasn't such a good explanation, here's a picture:

[image]

If the question list could be collapsed, it would make it so much easier to use.

Btw, *sometimes* the whole screen is used, such as when clicking a link, or after posting.

Comment: Oh, yes. This would be excellent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask, and ye shall receive. (It's the holidays, after all).

During the development of the split view, the problem you describe always bothered me. However, having a button to split/collapse between the two modes felt like an ugly solution.

Instead, I decided to **only show the split setup when the device is in the landscape** orientation. When in portrait, the question will take up all the screen, and the question list will be tucked into the stack. (That means you can still get to it by tapping on the back button).

[image]

These changes are a bit hard to picture, so I've included a [little screencast](http://quick.as/d3gqhdqg) too.

This feature is available in **beta version 1.2.0.173**.